# Injective function from $\Bbb N^3 \to \Bbb N$?

Tags: number-theory

What is an injective function from $\Bbb N^3 \to \Bbb N$?

I imagine I just want to create a list, essentially to show that this is countable. But I can't come up with such a list. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your $\Bbb N$ include $0$?

Comment: Use distinct primes $p_1, p_2, p_3$ and map $(n_1, n_2, n_3) \mapsto p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}p_3^{n_3}$. By uniqueness of prime factorisation this is injective!

Comment: @SEWillB this should be the answer! (i.e. you can post it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As requested, I shall post my comment as an answer. We can use distinct primes $p_1, p_2, p_3$ and the map $(n_1, n_2, n_3) \mapsto p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}p_3^{n_3}$
Then we get injectivity by uniqueness of prime factorisation.
I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to take advantage of the [Cantor Pairing Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) that provides a bijection from $\mathbb N^2$ to $\mathbb N$:
$$
\begin{align}
\pi(x,y)&=T_{(x+y)}+y\\
&=\frac12(x+y)(x+y+1)+y
\end{align}
$$
where $T_n$ denotes the [$n$-th triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). From this you can form the bijection from $\mathbb N^3$ to $\mathbb N$ given by
$$
f(x,y,z)=\pi(\pi(x,y),z)
$$
Note that $0$ is included in $\mathbb N$ in this version of $\pi$.

---

Or we could build a function similar to that of Cantor adding an extra dimension:
$$
\begin{align}
g(x,y,z)&=P_{(x+y+z)}+T_{(x+y)}+x\\
&=\binom{x+y+z+2}{3}+\binom{x+y+1}{2}+x
\end{align}
$$
where $P_n$ denotes the [$n$-th tetrahedral number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number). Again with $0$ included in $\mathbb N$. This provides another bijection.